# Services can't communicate because there is not DNS resolving in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I configure my services with type ClusterIP. And I want to make them communicated.

## Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 labels:
  app: app-backend-deployment
 name: app-backend
spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 ports:
 - port: 8020
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 8100
 selector:
  app: app-backend
```

## Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 labels:
  app: app-backend
 name: app-backend-deployment
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-backend
 template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-backend
    spec:
     containers:
     - name: app-backend
       image: app-backend
       ports:
       - containerPort: 8100
       imagePullPolicy: Never
```

## ConfigMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: backend-conf # name of configMap
data:
  BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST: app-backend:8020
```

And that is what I pass to the frontend service, and I want to make a REST call through the DNS name for example http://app-backend:8020/get/1. But like I see in the console app cannot resolve DNS name `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

I also check pod nslookup:

```
busybox nslookup app-backend.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

Name:   app-backend.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.106.41.36
```

And compare it to

```
kubectl describe svc app-backend
Name:              app-backend
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=app-backend-deployment
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"...
Selector:          app=app-backend
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.106.41.36
Port:              <unset>  8020/TCP
TargetPort:        8100/TCP
```

And like you can see there is the same IP on Address but I don't know and where to look what is wrong why dns resolver doesn't work.  `kubectl version Client "v1.15.5", Server Version:"v1.17.3",`

Comment: Where are you making that failing DNS lookup? That name is only valid within the cluster.

Comment: What kind of thing is the "frontend service"?  Is it another Kubernetes pod, or something else?

Comment: @BurakSerdar inside a pod app-backend-deployment-78856bd74-s2pq5

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, this is another service Angular app on ngninx with different pod and service

Comment: When you say "Angular", is the actual REST request coming from a browser application?  That won't be able to use Kubernetes DNS.

Comment: @DavidMaze  yes that sounds correct because I think it coming from a browser I have to make that communication through the ingress.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? @Adriano

Comment: Yes I communicate via Ingress with backend service

Comment: How did you solve it? Can you provide the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of that frontend service that was served to the local machine (that how Angular works) REST request cannot go through Kubernetes DNS with another backend service. I need to communicate them through the Ingress. Due to different annotations, I have to use 2 Ingress. Meaby there is a better way to use just one, but when I want to use only one Ingress I can't find a way to make them both working, with the same annotation.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
 name: app-backend-ingress
spec:
 rules:
 - host: app.io
   http:
     paths:
       - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
         backend:
          serviceName: app-backend
          servicePort: 8020
---  
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
 name: app-frontend-ingress
spec:
 rules:
 - host: app.io
   http:
     paths:
       - path: /
         backend:
          serviceName: app-frontend
          servicePort: 80
```